# PhantomJS: how to execute function on webpage

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I need to execute simple script that cliks buttons on website. After some research and reading documentation I made this script:

```
page.open('http://www.somewebsite.com/', function (status) {

    if (status !== "success") {
        console.log("Unable to access network");
    } else {
        console.log("Page loaded");

        page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {

            page.evaluate (function() {

                function bump_trades() {

                    var xpr = document.evaluate(".//li/a[@class='trade_bump']/div[@class='icon_bump']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
                    var anchor;

                    while (anchor = xpr.iterateNext()) {
                        anchor = anchor.parentNode;                     
                        if (anchor.getAttribute('data-tradeid'))
                            break;
                    }
                    if (anchor && anchor.getAttribute('data-tradeid')) {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                                anchor.click();
                                setTimeout(bump_trades, 500);                               
                            }, 500);
                    } else {
                    }               
                };  
                bump_trades();
            }); 
            console.log('Exit');
            phantom.exit();
        });
    };  
});
```

The script itself (starting from var xpr...)in browser console works just fine, no problems. But when in PhantomJS it is doing nothing. I have console message that page is loaded, but script do not executes. 
I am very new in Javascript, please help me figure out where is the problem.

Comment: Do you see the Test Timeout output before Exit ?

Comment: No, just because it executes on webpage, not in PhantomJS console. Removed it.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting timeout, but you are exiting before it is actually executed. Move the phantom.exit() call in a timeout.

Comment: Thank you for quick responce, I put the phantom.exit() call in a setTimeout function, and now I got "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'anchor.click()')" Updated the code btw, I forgot the bump_trades() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable that that is set to true when the long running function in the page context should terminate. You can then use the <kbd>[`waitFor`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js)</kbd> construct to wait in the phantom context for the exit. So change

```
page.evaluate (function() {
    function bump_trades() {
        // your code        
    };  
    bump_trades();
}); 
console.log('Exit');
phantom.exit();
```

to

```
page.evaluate (function() {
    function bump_trades() {
        var xpr = document.evaluate(".//li/a[@class='trade_bump']/div[@class='icon_bump']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var anchor;

        while (anchor = xpr.iterateNext()) {
            anchor = anchor.parentNode;                     
            if (anchor.getAttribute('data-tradeid'))
                break;
        }
        if (anchor && anchor.getAttribute('data-tradeid')) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                    anchor.click();
                    setTimeout(bump_trades, 500);                               
                }, 500);
        } else {
            window.bumpTradesCompleted = true;
        }               
    };  
    window.bumpTradesCompleted = false;
    bump_trades();
});
waitFor(function testFx(){
    return page.evaluate(function(){
        return window.bumpTradesCompleted;
    });
}, function onReady(){
    phantom.exit();
}, 1000000); // wait a long time
```

The `waitFor` function looks like this:

```
function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 3000, //< Default Max Timout is 3s
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        condition = false,
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                condition = (typeof(testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
            } else {
                if(!condition) {
                    // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                    phantom.exit(1);
                } else {
                    // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                    typeof(onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condition is fulfilled
                    clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                }
            }
        }, 250); //< repeat check every 250ms
};
```

Comment: Thank you for responce! I will try to figure out what your code is doing step-by-step. Now I just copy-pasted it and get the same error "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'anchor.click()')" . Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) for `console.log` debugging in the page context.